# Displaying linkable search results + alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My first steps in JS. (Please ignore the ugly image near each result) :)

Questions:
1. Do somebody know why not all the links appear as clickable?
2. How can I align the link titles to the center of each picture?
3. How can I remove the annoying bullets?

Thanks!

For complete code please look [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/qfdf186x/1/). (Jsfiddle)

```
var list1 = [{"link":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Balloon","title":"Balloon - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloons.com\/","title":"Balloons.com - Wholesale Balloon Distributor"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.partycity.com\/category\/balloons.do","title":"Party Balloons, Helium Balloons & Balloon Accessories - Party City"},{"link":"http:\/\/clashofclans.wikia.com\/wiki\/Balloon","title":"Balloon - Clash of Clans Wiki"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloon-juice.com\/","title":"Balloon Juice"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloonfiesta.com\/","title":"The Albuquerque International Balloon Fiesta - Welcome to the ..."},{"link":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=belCJJjut1A","title":"\"The Balloon Show\" for learning colors -- children's educational video"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/loon\/","title":"Loon for All \u2013 Project Loon \u2013 Google"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=khsXGETCqVw","title":"\"Pretty Balloons\" (balloon song for learning colors) - YouTube"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloon-app.com\/","title":"Balloon"}]


function DisplayListItems(list1) {      
        $.each(list1, function(index, element) {
            var itemHTML = ["<li>",
                               "<div>",
                                 "<img src='http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif' height='200' width='200' />",
                                 "<a href=" + element.link + ">" + element.title + "</a>",                         
                               "</div>",
                           "</li>"].join('\n');
            $(".list > ul").append(itemHTML);
        });
      }

DisplayListItems(list1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for all three questions.

1. quotes missing from the anchor href
2. add list-item:none; for li
3. you can see how i solved it

```js
 var list1 = [{"link":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Balloon","title":"Balloon - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloons.com\/","title":"Balloons.com - Wholesale Balloon Distributor"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.partycity.com\/category\/balloons.do","title":"Party Balloons, Helium Balloons & Balloon Accessories - Party City"},{"link":"http:\/\/clashofclans.wikia.com\/wiki\/Balloon","title":"Balloon - Clash of Clans Wiki"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloon-juice.com\/","title":"Balloon Juice"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloonfiesta.com\/","title":"The Albuquerque International Balloon Fiesta - Welcome to the ..."},{"link":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=belCJJjut1A","title":"\"The Balloon Show\" for learning colors -- children's educational video"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/loon\/","title":"Loon for All \u2013 Project Loon \u2013 Google"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=khsXGETCqVw","title":"\"Pretty Balloons\" (balloon song for learning colors) - YouTube"},{"link":"http:\/\/www.balloon-app.com\/","title":"Balloon"}]


function DisplayListItems(list1) {  
  $.each(list1, function(index, element) {
      var itemHTML = ["<li>",
                               "<div class='cont'>",
               "<img src='http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif' height='200' width='200' />",
               "<a width='200'  height='200px' href='" + element.link + "'><span>" + element.title + "</span></a>",         
                "</div>",
            "</li>"].join('\n');
      $(".list > ul").append(itemHTML);
  });
   }

DisplayListItems(list1);
```

```css
li{
    list-style:none;
}
.cont
{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
}

.cont img
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.cont a
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    display: block;
}

a span {
    display:inline;
    display:inline-table;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 20px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

There are many solutions to the 3rd problem. eg . You can give the image as background of the link.[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfdf186x/3/).

```
<a width='200'  height='200px' href='" + element.link + "' style='background-image: url(\"http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/sunset.gif\");background-size: cover;'><span>" + element.title + "</span></a>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have forgotten the quotes:

```
 "<a href='" + element.link + "'>" + element.title + "</a>",
```

Comment: Great, have an idea for questions 2,3?
By the way how could it be that some of the links were okay and other not?

Comment: @JavaSa check my answer. It solves all the problems.

Comment: @JavaSa tkay has answered the rest of your questions, a little research on that would have been sufficient ;-) The rest is css stuff, no js.